# App freezes on IOS when navigate to another screen - React Navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

**Current Behavior**
Ios app freezing when I want to navigate from Page1 to Page2

**Expected Behavior**
I have two simple pages and I want to go to from Page1 to Page2 like

```
<Button title = "Go to Page2" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Page2")} />
```

But on IOS simulator when I press to Button or TouchableOpacity, app is freezing and can not go to another screen. Actually page 2 is loading in background but screen can not update itself.

**Page1.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class Page1 extends Component{
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Page 1</Text>
                <Button title = "Go to page 2" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Page2")} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**Page2.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Page2 extends Component{
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("This is page 2 and, I can see this from console.");
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>I'm in Page 2</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**Router.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Page1 from "./Page1";
import Page2 from "./Page2";

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
        Page1: {
            screen: Page1
        },
        Page2: {
            screen: Page2
        }
    }, {
        initialRouteName: "Page1",
    }
);
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-facebook-account-kit": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-iap": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

**Podfile**

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
       'Core',
       'CxxBridge',
       'DevSupport',
       'RCTText',
       'RCTNetwork',
       'RCTWebSocket',
       'RCTAnimation',
       'RCTActionSheet',
       'RCTBlob',
       'RCTCameraRoll',
       'RCTGeolocation',
       'RCTImage',
       'RCTPushNotification',
       'RCTSettings',
       'RCTTest',
       'RCTVibration',
       'RCTLinkingIOS'
     ]
     pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
     pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
     pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
     pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
     pod 'RNAccountKit', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-facebook-account-kit/ios'
     pod 'RNIap', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-iap'
     pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'
     pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
     pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
```

**Environment**

```
React Native Environment Info:
System:
OS: macOS 10.14.4
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 209.52 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 10.15.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2
Android SDK:
API Levels: 24, 26, 27, 28, 29
Build Tools: 19.1.0, 20.0.0, 21.1.2, 22.0.1, 23.0.2, 25.0.0, 26.0.2, 27.0.0, 28.0.3, 29.0.0, 29.0.0
System Images: android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156
Xcode: 10.2.1/10E1001 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3
react-native: 0.59.8 => 0.59.8
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native-rename: 2.4.1
```

Comment: It all looks okay to me.  Have you tried setting Page2 as your initial screen and see if it loads properly?

Comment: Yes I tried. On Android everything looks good. I think an IOS package or react-navigation on IOS cause this issue. Did you try with my dependencies?

Comment: This code must give you an error. Because `createStackNavigator`, `createAppContainer` are not imported in you `Router.js` file. Also you imported Page2 from "./Page1".

Comment: @firats I added those two lines to here. App is working correctly until I press button. Also Android platform working well.

Comment: @hakiko i see. but you still have `import Page2 from "./Page1";`. Is that true Page2 is coming from the same path with Page1?

Comment: @firats No I just typed here manually. Actual code path is ./Page2

Comment: Tested on my machine, it seems ok. My suggestion is create a new app and implement navigation first before the other dependencies and see if the code works.

Comment: @firats I tested with a new and empty react-native app and it is working correctly. But especially fbsdk and account kit configs getting my hours. So I should fix this stupid error without new app config.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, I spend almost 1week to solve it. Your pod file is the issue.

in subspecs

'Core',
 'RCTLinkingIOS'

you only need these two. Change your pod file, and do `pod install`. If you get any error, add the missing subspec and do `pod install`. The culprit is one of the item in subspecs.

Comment: You're right. Also I spent my three days. Then I installed my packages manually without Pod file. So which subspec causing this bug? Did you find it?

Comment: Not exactly. I removed every unwanted podsecs from it. I only use 'Core', 'RCTLinkingIOS' and RCTImage

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and @CRYadu's answer helped. I ended up clearing out my dependencies and then reinstalling from scratch solved the problem.

```
rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json
npm install
npm run pods
npm start
npm run ios
```